# Issues with newlines and literal \n when pickling strings

Tags: python, newline, pickle

```
postoption=input("Press 1 to leave a post, and 2 to close The Wall.")
        if postoption=="2":
            print("Wall closed.")
        elif postoption=="1":
            wally=pickle.load(open("The Wall.txt","rb"))
            usernamey=pickle.load(open("username1.txt","rb"))
            wu="\n",(wally),"\n",(usernamey)
            apost=input("Enter your post below: \n")
            pwickle=pickle.dump((wu, apost), open("The Wall.txt","wb"))
            print(pwickle)
        else:
            print("Wall closed.")
```

This code will leave "\n"s instead of new lines because it is re-reading what is saved in the .txt file. What is the easiest way to stop this?

Comment: that is **not** a text file - that's a binary file that stores pickle information. where do you get the extra \n's?